# Java EE war deployment or redeployment - automatically choose the appropriate action

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, cargo

In development, it's fairly common to want to deploy your war to your local app server, irrespective of whether it's already deployed (i.e. just deploy over the old version, if it's there).

However both cargo and the glassfish maven plugin fail under the following circumstances:

- 'redeploy', if war is not already deployed,
- 'deploy', if it's already deployed.

As a developer, I don't want to have to choose one or the other. Is there a single command that will enable deployment to succeed in both use cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cargo:redeploy` now works as expected in cargo 1.1.3 (at least with glassfish)

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but as a workaround you can use

```
mvn cargo:undeploy cargo:deploy
```

If i recall correctly, the cargo:undeploy target won't fail if the application is not deployed and maven will proceed with the cargo:deploy target.

Comment: I found that cargo:undeploy does fail, unfortunately. Otherwise that would be a perfect workaround.

Comment: I just tried it on a project using maven 3.0.3 and cargo 1.0.6. Cargo issued a warning about the application not being deployed and the proceed to deploy it. You can see the results [here](https://gist.github.com/1194590).

Comment: Tried again, get `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.1.2:undeploy (undeploy) on project [project]: Execution undeploy of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.1.2:undeploy failed: Cannot find the module "[module]". Available modules: -> [Help 1]` and the build fails.

Comment: For an 'installed' type deployer, that works, but not 'remote'. I'll upvote anyway since it could be helpful for situations with local a deployment.